# How to solve "Not available" error for ASP.NET version in MS WebMatrix deploy compatibility check?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, web-deployment

I'm trying to publish my brand new Umbraco 5 installation to my own Windows VPS. So I made a website, enabled web deploy, etc.

It is possible to connect when I click Validate Connection under Publish Settings.

When I do the compatibility check, the Simple HTML Pages passes saying: Available.
The ASP.net version however says: Not available.

On Google people said it could be the .net version and pipeline. My local website runs ASP.net 4.0 (integrated) and so does my remote.

I certainly have no clue what could be the problem. Do you?

Thanks in advance for your time,
Thom Hubers

Update:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/988/microsoft-webmatrix-publish-compatibility/?language=en-US
This link says: "Check if your hosting provider supports ASP.NETCheck if your hosting provider has given you permissions to change your IIS application pool’s .NET framework version and pipeline mode" Well, yes, I support ASP.NET. And since I'm my own hosting provider, I have permissions to change the .NET version and pipeline mode. But I really don't know what the problem is, since the local and remote are both 4.0 integrated. (tried other combinations too)

Answer (score 0):

Is your remote server you publishing to an IIS 7+ system? If so then, to publish to it you can use either the Web Management Service (WMSvc) end point or Web Deployment Agent end point.

If you specify just your remote computername in publish dialog of VS it will default to WMSvc and use the url https://yourcomputer.domain.com:8172/msdeploy.axd.
If you want to use the agent specify, http://yourcomputer.domain.com/msdeployagentservice.

If its IIS6 then web deployment agent is the only option.

Can you give some more information about your environment?